# Django installed but not able to locate module

Tags: django, referenceerror

[image: 1]

I'm using a django web project template and its my first time creating one. I had to pip install django but the code that is existing still isnt referencing it and instead its giving a green squiggle under neath anything referencing Django. I created another blank file and ran a line with import django and it removed the green squiggles and worked. But then I dont know what changed and now its back to how it was before and even running import django before my code wont fix it like last time. It still gives the error below. I havent typed any new code to this template so there should not be any errors with the code provided.

I tried first to add a new empty python file and import django. It worked the first time but went away and didnt work the second time.
I tried to type import django before each file that uses django functions. It didn't remove the squiggles. From what I can tell when I run the whole file it pulls up a website with django on it and does not error out.

Answer (score 0):

you can n't import django as module . django is framework
just proceed this document
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/